Constructing a container without duplicating data on disk
For Reasons*, I'm using a container to distribute a versioned Windows virtual machine file, which is around 40G in size.
I've got the following command:
echo -e "FROM scratch\nADD VM_2024-05-15_win11.img Win11-2024-05-15.qcow2" \
   | podman build --layers=false --cpu-shares 8 -t gitlab.example.com:5050/ci-windows:win11vm-2024-05-15

Now this is all well and good and works well, other than the amount of storage space required to actually construct it. It seems that podman takes about 5 copies of the internal data to actually construct the container. I've managed to reduce it by 1 copy with --layers=false, but it still seems like a lot. I've also set the TMPDIR environment variable to ensure podman actually does its copying on the right drive.
Is there anything else I can do to reduce the amount of disk space required to build this container? Ideally there'd just be one copy where it takes the img file and places it directly into the completed continer.
Additionally, the time it takes to compress what is already a fairly solidly compressed binary seems to take forever too - I recognise that it's quite a lot that needs compressing, but it feels like that could be sped up too - doesn't seem like --cpu-shares is having any affect.
*Gitlab container registry is really convenient

Does piping a tarball to podman import use less space? tar -cf- . | podman import - my-new-image

And interesting idea (well, podman image load), but constructing the tar archive format would be a bit tricky with all the hashes and various other metadata that would need constructing manually. Any thoughts on doing that?

I was suggesting podman import, which just takes a regular tar file as input. podman image load is a different thing, and I wouldn't go that route, at least not as a first choice. If you try my previous suggestion, does it result it less disk space consumption?
